# Convert Dynamic Json to Something more Concrete

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

How can I deserialize the JSON below to a C# array or something more manageable.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "PropertyName": [
        {
          "Key1": "test",
          "Key2": "afafa"
        },
        {
          "Key1": "test",
          "Key2": "afafa"
        }
      ],
      "PropertyName2": [
        {
          "Key1": "test",
          "Key2": "afafa"
        },
        {
          "Key1": "test",
          "Key2": "afafa"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It comes in as a dynamic parameter like this:

```
public IActionResult SAve([FromBody] dynamic mapping)
```

I normally would make this a concrete class but "PropertyName" will change to different names, so I need something flexible.  The contents of it can be concrete as it is just two properties.

I am thinking that it could be like a dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, ConcreteClass>()
```

I just don't know how to get it into that form.

Edit.

I have gone ahead and did the suggestion but it does not work

```
{{
  "data": [
    {
      "propertyName": [
        {
          "key1": 1,
          "key2": "1"
        },
        {
          "key1": 2,
          "key2": "2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}}
```

I tried to convert like this

```
 var ddd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MappingDto>>(mapping.data.ToString());
```

this makes an empty object in the array. If I don't have it wrapped in a collection then I get a different error

```
 public class MappingDto
    {
        public List<Dictionary<string, List<Item>>> Items { get; set; }
    }

  public class Items
    {
        public string Key1{ get; set; }
        public string Key2{ get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: You could use JObject. Then, for example, you can use indexers to access properties by string names like a dictionary, but more dynamic.

Comment: You could write your own JsonConverter. Here is an example: [Deserializing different JSON structures to the same C# class](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/deserialize-different-json-object-same-class/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this JSON, a concrete class structure that handles the dynamic property names as you described would look like this:

```
public class MappingDto
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, List<Item>>> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Key1 { get; set; }
    public string Key2 { get; set; }
}
```

Be sure to update your method signature to use the new class instead of `dynamic`:

```
public IActionResult SAve([FromBody] MappingDto mapping)
```

You can then access the data like this (for example):

```
foreach (var dict in mapping.Data)
{
    foreach (var kvp in dict)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(kvp.Key);
        foreach (var item in kvp.Value)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(" Key1: " + item.Key1); 
            Debug.WriteLine(" Key2: " + item.Key2); 
        }
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OGylPh

Comment: Hmm, this does not seem to work. I think it is something because of the dynamic? It has an extra layer or braces. I will update my post to show this.

Comment: You said in your original question that you wanted to replace the `dynamic` with something concrete, so I was assuming you were going to update the method signature accordingly.  If you do that, it should work as intended.  I've updated my answer to show this step.  You shouldn't need to make a separate call inside your method to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`.

Comment: Also, don't change the name of the `Data` property in the `MappingDto` class to `Items` or else it won't match the JSON and you'll get an empty list.  The JSON you posted has a `data` key at the root which matches up to this property.

Comment: Also, FYI, if your JSON *really* has an extra layer of braces like that, it is invalid.  I suspect you are copying the JSON out of your debugger?  The Visual Studio debugger adds those extra braces for some reason.  They should not be in the real data.   You can check it for yourself using a JSON validator such as [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Yea I was looking through VS so yea that might be the reason, however I am still getting empty object even when I change it to "data".

Comment: Did you change your method signature to use the MappingDto instead of dynamic?

Comment: Yea that was the problem, I did not see that you changed it from dynamic.